# Strange experience with subversion

Tags: svn

I first created the `/trunk` on `domain.name`

```
svnadmin create /trunk
svnserve -d -r /trunk
```

Then I tried to connect to `svn://domain.name/trunk`,but it doesn't exists...

So I tried `svn://domain.name/`,this time it works...

Why my repository `/trunk` maps to `/`?

Answer (score 0):

Your first command created a repository in the `/trunk` directory.
You have not created a 'trunk' directory *inside* a repository.  You've created a repository in a directory called trunk.

Your second command then started an svn server to host this repository.
When you pass in `-r /trunk` to svnserve you're saying you want svn://domain.name/ to point to the /trunk folder of the filesystem.

I'd suggest trying the following to create an empty repository and add a trunk directory to it:

```
mkdir /repository
svnadmin create /repository
svnserve -d -r /repository
svn mkdir -m "Making trunk directory." svn://domain.name/trunk
```

Alternatively, instead of the `svn mkdir` command, you could checkout the empty repository, add the required content and then check it back in. For example:

```
cd ~
svn co svn://domain.name/ myWorkingCopy
cd myWorkingCopy
mkdir trunk
cp /path/to/existing/codebase trunk/ 
svn add trunk
svn ci -m "First commit of trunk codebase"
```